# Process Input Stream

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to simulate a command prompt using swing text area. I am starting a server and passing the stream to the text area. The problem is, I am not able to see the console output in the text area. How to fix it?

I can able to see the console output once the process is dead (i.e. the server is stopped) until that time, I am not able to see the console output in the text area. Pasted the code chunk. I want the see the console output simultaneously when the server is up and running.

Note : "activator run" is the command to start the server.

```
private void startServerButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "activator run"};
    ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processbuilder.directory(new File("D:\\temp"));
    try {
        Process process = processbuilder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Appending the output to the text area
            cartServiceTextArea.append(line +"\n");
        }

        //Wait to get exit value
        try {
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DevUtilsUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't run blocking code in the event thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your loop in the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT) which updates the GUI. Till your method returns, the text area won't be updated. Anyhow, the approach is not correct.

What you need to do is to read the output from a separate thread and update the text area from there. You should not be blocking the EDT.

```
package ant.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAreaCommandOutput extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton executeServer;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TextAreaCommandOutput() {
        super("Execute Command and Output to TextArea");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 80);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
        executeServer = new JButton("Start Server");
        executeServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                executeServer.setEnabled(false);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        startServerButtonMouseClicked();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        add(executeServer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    private void startServerButtonMouseClicked() {
        String[] command = { "ls", "-lR" };
        ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        try {
            Process process = processbuilder.start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Appending the output to the text area
                textArea.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Wait to get exit value
            try {
                int exitValue = process.waitFor();
                System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TextAreaCommandOutput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        executeServer.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                TextAreaCommandOutput f = new TextAreaCommandOutput();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have done that. Now i modified the code as following still no use,

Comment: I don't know what you have done :). Updating my answer with a sample, see whether it helps.

Comment: You should be using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` for updating the textarea in the `startServerButtonMouseClicked` method. I didn't want to modify too much in your method, so I left it as it is.